# Laravel multi-language site database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, e-commerce

I am building an Laravel e-commerce site for Arabic and English languages.

Suppose I have Category table with title field. I want to insert title field in the two language. So I have created migration for `title_en` and `title_ar`.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use App\Traits\MultiLanguage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Category extends Model
{
    use MultiLanguage;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title_en', 'title_ar',
    ];
    /**
      * This array will have the attributes which you want it to support multi languages
    */
    protected $multi_lang = [
        'title',
    ];
}
```

Here is multi language traits:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
trait MultiLanguage
{

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if (isset($this->multi_lang) && in_array($key, $this->multi_lang)) {
            $key = $key . '_' . App::getLocale();
         }
        return parent::__get($key);
    }
}
```

But what to do when there are many table fields also, how to insert records. Is it possible?

Comment: I recommend using ready made free translatable spatie: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable

Comment: @OMR Sure, But this package useful when translation but what about store record in database.

Comment: you only have to make the column you want to translate a json column, then this trait will take care of the most operation for you

Comment: there is a brief "how to" in this address:https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable

Comment: @OMR Good, But this package handle insert multi Lang data?

Comment: of course, just read the doc, it's from spatie to handle multi lang data

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that having `title_en` and `title_ar` is a good idea. instead just have a `title` and an extra column named `lang` then query based on your language for instance
`FooModel::where('lang', $lang)->get();`

Comment: So that as per you think I need to add two row every time right?

Comment: Yes or you can even omit `lang` column and have 2 database one for english and 1 for arabic it's just depends on how big and scalable your project is.

Comment: and switch between your database connection based on your language @AmitSenjaliya

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya Then you can skip the DB and stick with the lang column and to make it easier you can make a `scope` to make your queries more dynamic https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes